# How to implement a "news" section in asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net

I'm implementing "news" section in asp.net website. There is a list of short versions of articles on one page and when you click one of the links it redirects you to a page with a full article. The problem is that the article's text on the second page will come from database but the articles may vary - some may have links, some may have an image or a set of images, may be differently formatted etc. The obvious solution that my friend have come up with is to keep the article in the database as html including all links, images, formatting, etc. Then it would be simply displayed on the second page. I feel this is not a good solution as if, for example, we decide to change the css class of some div inside this html (let's say it is used in all articles), we will have to find it and change in every single record of the articles table in our database. But on the other hand we have no idea how to do it differently. My question is: how do you usually handle something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like the idea of storing full html in the database.  Here's an attempt at solving the problem.

Don't go for a potentially infinite number of layouts.  Yes all articles may be different but if you stick to a few good layouts then you're going to save yourself a lot of hassle.  These layouts can be stored as templates e.g ArticleWithImagesAtTheBottom, ArticleWithImagesOnLeft etc

This way, your headache is less as you can easily change the templates.  I guess you could also argue then that the site has some consistency in layout.

Then for storage you have at least 2 options:

1. Use the model-per-view approach and have eg ArticleWithImagesAtTheBottomModel which would have properties like 1stparagraph, 2ndparagraph, MainImage, ExtraImages
2. Parse the article according to the template you want to use.  e.g look for a paragraph break if you need to.

Always keep the images separate and reference them in another column/table in the db.  That gives you most freedom.

By the way, option #2 would be slower as you'd have to parse on the fly each time.  I like the model-per-view approach.

Essentially I guess I'm trying to say beware of making things to complicated.  An infinite number of layout means an infinite number of potential problems.  You can always add more templates as you go if you really want to expand, but you're probably best off starting with say 3 or 4 layouts.

EDITED FROM THIS POINT:
Actually, thinking about it this may not be the best solution. It could work depending on your needs, but I was wondering how the big sites do it.  If you really need that much flexibility, you could (as I think was sort of suggested) use a custom markup. Maybe even a simplified or full wiki markup.  I'd still tend toward using templates in general, but if you need to insert at least links and images then you can parse for those.

Comment: This is all correct and you may be right, but it's impossible to tell from the little information the question has given. If they're news articles from external sources, it's not easy to convert them to special markup (like wiki markup, for instance).

Comment: yeah that's true. External sources would make my suggestions a huge pain

Answer (score 0):

Surely the point of storing HTML with logically placed < div >s is that you DON'T have to go through every bit of HTML you store to make changes to styles?

I presume you're not using inline styles in your stored HTML, and are referencing an external CSS file, right?

Comment: yes of course, it was just an example of a change that we may need to make one day to all of the articles' html, it may be so,ething different than css class

Comment: Truth be told, regardless of where/how you store your HTML, disk or database, if you make a change to all of your pages you are going to have to go through them all anyway. I suppose the ease of doing this simply depends on the toolset you build/buy/download.

Answer (score 0):

The objection you raise to your colleague's proposal does not say anything about the use of a DB. A DB as opposed to what: files? Then it's all the same. You want to screw around with the HTML, you have to do it on "every single record." Which is not any harder than "on every single file." Global changes are a bitch unless you plan for it by, say, referencing an external CSS. But if you're going to have millions of news articles, you had better plan on versioning the CSS as well.

Anyway, the CMSes do what you're thinking of doing. Using a DB is a fine way to go. How to use it would depend on knowing the problem more intimately.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked into using free content management systems?  I can think of a few good ones:

- Joomla
- Drupal
- WordPress
- TONS of others... just do some googling.

Check out this Wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems